# Change Linux boot logo

Tags: image-manipulation, images

I want to change the penguin logo that appears on boot. I looked into it and found this command:

```
pngtopnm nelogo.png | ppmquant -fs223| pnmtoplainpnm > logo_linux_clut224.ppm
```

But when I tried it I got this error message:

> unrecognized option `-fs223'
>   pnmtoplainpnm: EOF / read error reading magic number

What did I do wrong? How can I replace the boot logo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my (interpretation of, at least) manpages, the `-fs` option on `ppmquant` doesn't take an argument; the `ncolors` argument is separate.  Separate the `-fs 223`.  Not sure whether that will take care of the magic number error too.

Comment: Hi Kevin, you are correct. when I seperate -fs and 223 it worked fine. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have used jpegtopnm and a jpg pic, works like charm